# Using Google People API endpoint seachDirectoryPeople by externalId

Tags: python, google-api

I'm working with the People API in python, and using succesfully the searchDirectoryPeople service with this call:

```
people_service.people().searchDirectoryPeople(
    query='my name',
    readMask='externalIds',  
    sources=['DIRECTORY_SOURCE_TYPE_DOMAIN_PROFILE']
).execute()
```

And it returns this object:

```
{'people': [{'resourceName': 'people/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
   'etag': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
   'externalIds': [{'metadata': {'primary': True,
      'source': {'type': 'DOMAIN_PROFILE', 'id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'}},
     'value': 'MYUSERID',
     'type': 'Employee ID',
     'formattedType': 'Employee ID'}]}],
 'totalSize': 1}
```

The thing is that I tried different ways to use MYUSERID in the query parameter, but it never finds anything.
I tried with:

```
query='MYUSERID'
query='externalIds:MYUSERID'
query='MYUSERID in externalIds'
query='Employee ID=MYUSERID'
```

and every combination of : and =, but I haven't got success.

How should I write the query param to get the result?